# deleting files older than a specific day and excluding the direct files under folder

Tags: linux, shell-script, rhel, find, regular-expression

I would like to delete all files that older than 10 days from airflow sub folders

I used the following command:

```
 find  /var/log/airflow/  -type f -mtime +10  -delete
```

but excluding all the files that exist under airflow folder as: file1 , file2 , file3 , file4 , file5

```
pwd

/var/log/airflow

ls -ltr

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 6 Sep 13 11:15 folder1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 6 Sep 13 11:15 folder2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 6 Sep 13 11:15 folder3
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 6 Sep 13 11:15 folder4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 6 Sep 13 11:15 folder5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 11:15 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 11:15 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 11:15 file3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 11:15 file4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 13 11:15 file5
```

so all sub folders under airflow with their files will be effaced but not the files under airflow. In that case how can I change my command to support the excluding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all you need to do is add the -mindepth global option like this:

```
$ find /var/log/airflow/ -mindepth 2 -type f -mtime +10  -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

To tell `find` to look only in subfolders of /var/log/airflow, just give it those starting points:

```
shopt -s dotglob
find  /var/log/airflow/*/* -type f -mtime +10 -delete
```

This forces a subdirectory to exist under /var/log/airflow in order to match. I set `dotglob` so that any "hidden" directories under airflow are also matched.